# How to copy all the files from a folder but the symlink

Tags: zsh, symbolic-link

I'd like to copy **everything** recursively from a folder but the files symlinked from an other directory, how can I achieve that?

Comment: By `symlinked`, do you mean `files which are symlinks to other files` or `files who are symlinked somewhere else` ?

Comment: I updated my question, hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution

```
rsync -a --exclude='.*' --no-links . destfolder
```

I tested on my zsh and it copies everything recursively from the current folder except the symlinks and hidden files (bonus)

[Source](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html)

Answer (score 1):

how about:

`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} destfolder \;`

?

( or you meant "except files symlinked 'elsewhere' ? )

Comment: It works but it doesnt copy the symlink and the folders, I'd like to copy everything from a folder except the symlink

Comment: just tryied that same command in zsh+fedora17 and it worked. 
Any error out the copy command / did it find any file? ( -maxdepth 1 = looking only in that dir, not in subdir ).

Eventually, check found files via:

find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print